# Multilevel php array for json string. Output wrong

Tags: php, arrays, json, multi-level

I try to generate a multilevel PHP Array with a DB-Connection that i can encode in JSON. 
The output have an square-bracket-pair to much that i want to remove.

I have following php-code

```
## Step 1 #################
    do{
    $tabContent[] = array
        (
            "name" => $row_profile['name'],
            "titel" => $row_profile['titel']
        );
}while ($row_profile = $statement_profile->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

## Step 2 #################
$tabelled['repositories'] = array 
    (
        $tabContent
    );


## Step 3 #################
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($tabelled, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

So now i have the following response:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        [
            {
                "name": "test",
                "titel": "a sdfaf"
            },
            {
                "name": "Frank wieder",
                "titel": "test test"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

but i need following output

```
{
  "repositories": [
    {
        "name": "test",
        "titel": "a sdfaf"
    },
    {
        "name": "Frank wieder",
        "titel": "test test"
    }
  ]
}
```

So the error is on step 1 the square bracket after the variable $tabContent. But without i cannot make the multilevel array. 
What can i do, to remove the second square bracket after "repositories"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $tabContent is already an array, and you're wrapping it inside of an extra array.  Without that, it should come out as expected.

```
$tabelled['repositories'] = $tabContent;
```